# How does Spark work with a JDBC connection?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Spark and I am trying to work on a `spark-jdbc` program to count the number of rows in a database.

I have come up with this code:

```
object PartitionRetrieval {
    var conf  = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark-JDBC")
    val log   = LogManager.getLogger("Spark-JDBC Program")
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val conFile       = "/home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/testconnection.properties"
    val properties    = new Properties()
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(conFile))
    val connectionUrl = properties.getProperty("gpDevUrl")
    val devUserName   = properties.getProperty("devUserName")
    val devPassword   = properties.getProperty("devPassword")
    val driverClass   = properties.getProperty("gpDriverClass")
    val tableName     = "source.bank_accounts"
    try {
    Class.forName(driverClass).newInstance()
    } catch {
    case cnf: ClassNotFoundException =>
        log.error("Driver class: " + driverClass + " not found")
        System.exit(1)
    case e: Exception =>
        log.error("Exception: " + e.printStackTrace())
        System.exit(1)
    }
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark   = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
        val gpTable = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                                                        .option("dbtable",tableName)
                                                        .option("user",devUserName)
                                                        .option("password",devPassword).load()
        val rc = gpTable.filter(gpTable("source_system_name")==="ORACLE").count()
        println("gpTable Count: " + rc)
    }
}
```

So far, this code is working. But I have 2 conceptual doubts about this.

1. In Java, we create a connection class and use that connection to query multiple tables and close it once our requirement is met. But it appears to work in a different way.
   If I have to query 10 tables in a database, should I use this line 10 times with different tables names in it:
   In Java, we create a connection class and use that connection to query multiple tables and close it once our requirement is met. But it appears to work in a different way.
   If I have to query 10 tables in a database, should I use this line 10 times with different tables names in it:

   ```
   val gpTable = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                                                   .option("dbtable",tableName)
                                                   .option("user",devUserName)
                                                   .option("password",devPassword).load()
   ```
2. The current table used here has total rows of 2000. I can use the filter/select/aggregate functions accordingly.
   But in our production there are tables with millions of rows and if I put one of the huge table in the above statement, even though our requirement has  filtering it later, wouldn't is create a huge dataframe first?

Could anyone care to give me some insight regarding the doubts I mentioned above?

Comment: How are things progressing?

Comment: Very well my friend 

Comment: SO is good site - despite the criticisms that one can read out there on the web

Comment: I second your opinion sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an SQL query to it first known as pushdown to database.

E.g.

```
val dataframe_mysql = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "(select k, v from sample where k = 1) e", connectionProperties)
```

You can substitute with s""" the k = 1 for hostvars, or, build your own SQL string and reuse as you suggest, but if you don't the world will still exist.